# I can´t insert new data into my database with javaDB

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

i am developing a program to test how to use Derby from Java..

The problem is that i can´t add data from the IDE to my database, because after run my program. The data are not reflected on the DB.

Look my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="DBExamplePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>exampleDB.sql.Provincia</class>
    <class>exampleDB.sql.Persona</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:example;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is the code that i am trying to insert new data:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DBExamplePU"); // Comprobar nombre de la PU
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // OPERACIONES DE BD
    Provincia provinciaCadiz = new Provincia(0, "Cádiz");

    Provincia provinciaSevilla = new Provincia();
    provinciaSevilla.setNombre("Sevilla");

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(provinciaCadiz);
    em.persist(provinciaSevilla);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.close();
    emf.close();
    try {
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:DBExamplePU;shutdown=true");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
```

In the platform netbeans IDE the data aren´t reflected on the database, but when i run this:

```
List<Provincia> listProvincias = queryProvincias.getResultList();
    for(int i=0; i<listProvincias.size(); i++) {
        Provincia provincia = listProvincias.get(i);
        System.out.println(provincia.getNombre());
    }
```

it shows me correctly the data!.

is like the database that i am using in my code is different from the database that i have created previously..

Hope you can help me, thank you!.

Comment: Any errors? Logs? Are you eating the exception that it might have been throwing?

Comment: No, just the data are not reflected in the DB

Comment: "jdbc:derby:example;create=true" is different from "jdbc:derby:DBExamplePU;shutdown=true". You don't show the code that is failing to find the data in the database, but perhaps it is not looking at the right database?

Comment: It´s because i am trying to see the data from the netBeans IDE platform, and without using code.

Comment: Question edited, provided more details..